# Combine rows from different files, if pattern is matched

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

Input: two tab-delimited files, `File1` and `File2`. `File2` (`$2`) has to be parsed by patterns found in `File1` (`$1`).

Expected output: tab-delimited file, `File3`. `File3` has to contain the same rows as `File2`, plus the corresponding value in `File1` if the pattern is matched (end of the line, tab-separated).

File1 (tab-delimited):

```
ABC1    1    3
ABC2    4    3
ABC3    3    2
ABC4    3    3
```

File2 (tab-delimited):

```
text1   ABC1-AB   text2   text3
text2   ABC2-AB   text1   
text3   ABC1-CD   text2
text4   ABC5-AB   text3   text4
```

File3:

```
text1   ABC1-AB   text2   text3    1    3
text2   ABC2-AB   text1    4    3
text3   ABC1-CD   text2    1    3
text4   ABC5-AB   text3   text4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2"\t"$3} FNR!=NR{split($2,b,"-"); $0=$0"\t"a[b[1]];print}' file1 file2
```

- `FNR==NR` applies to the first file `file1`:

  - `a[$1]=$2"\t"$3` fill the array `a` with the 2nd and 3rd field and as index use the 1st field.
- `FNR!=NR` applies to the second file `file2`:

  - `split($2,b,"-")` splits the 2nd field at `-`.
  - `$0=$0"\t"a[b[1]]` appends the two values to the line.
  - `print` prints the line.

The output:

```
text1   ABC1-AB text2   text3   1   3
text2   ABC2-AB text1   4   3
text3   ABC1-CD text2   1   3
text4   ABC5-AB text3   text4
```

Comment: Alright, so your solution will work if the character `-` is the only one found in the whole row, otherwise it will screw up the entire row. I'm really looking for something that could "scan" File2,$2 for pattern in File1,$1 and append the corresponding values. Thanks

Comment: @Dovah I changed my answer, It now only splits the 2nd field by dash. Is that what you wanted? Or do you mean by "scan" to search in the 2nd field?

Answer (score 2):

Tested using BASH.

```
while read LINEFILE2
do
  printf "$LINEFILE2" >> File3
  while read LINEFILE1
  do
    read PATTERN ADDITIONS <<EOF
$LINEFILE1
EOF
    [ ! -z "$PATTERN" ] && [ ! -z $(echo "$LINEFILE2" | cut -f2 | grep "$PATTERN") ] && {
      printf "\t$ADDITIONS\n" >> File3
    }
  done < File1
done < File2
```

If you would like the pattern to be found inside the entire line and not only in column 2 you could get the `cut` command out of the pipe construction.